# Trying to create an undo function that's triggered by a button click in canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am testing things right now (just started out with web development a few days ago) so I pretty much just copied and pasted the undo function from http://www.codicode.com/art/undo_and_redo_to_the_html5_canvas.aspx. Right now I am unable to access the full source code so i'm kinda just guessing where to place things.

Here is a snippet of the code that I think is relevant to the question:

```
var cPushArray = new Array();
var cStep = -1;
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

function cPush() {
    cStep++;
    if (cStep < cPushArray.length) {
        cPushArray.length = cStep;
    }
    cPushArray.push(document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL());
}

function cUndo() {
    if (cStep > 0) {
        cStep--;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
        canvasPic.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}

//This draws the dots on the face.   
function drawCoordinates(x, y) {
    var pointSize = 3; // Change according to the size of the point.
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626";
    ctx.beginPath(); //Start path
    ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Draw a point using the arc function of the canvas with a point structure.
    ctx.fill(); // Close the path and fill.
    cPush();
}

//count variable keeps track of the flicks
var count = 1;

//this listens for button clicks and displays the elements
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById(count).style.display = "block";
    count++;
}
document.getElementById('buttonUndo').onclick = function() {
    cUndo();
}
```

So far I know for a fact that the undo button is correctly linked because when I code `alert("hello")`, the alert pops up when the button is clicked. However, the undo function doesn't do anything in the code and i'm having trouble figuring out why it's behaving that way and how to fix it.

Comment: `cUndo` will only undo what was done when `cPush` was called. Make sure you're calling `cPush` after modifying the canvas.

Comment: in your `cUndo()` function it checks for `if (cStep > 0)` so everything inside that block will only run if cStep is greater than 0.

Comment: @MikeC That makes sense! I just modified the code so that cPush is called after the drawCoordinates but still, nothing happens.

Comment: @LunZhang Right! But even after I modify cStep to be something like >-2, still nothing happens. I've also tried drawing multiple dots (to increase the cStep count) and then undoing, but it fails.

Comment: make sure that canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep]; is returning a src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the canvas needs to be cleared. When you do `ctx.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0)` that's saying "draw the previous state of the canvas over what's currently on the canvas." The problem is that the previous canvas state had clear or empty pixels on it. So it's like using a stamp with *only* the stuff that was actually drawn last time. Meaning the "blank" parts of the stamp aren't going to erase any part of the current screen. [You can fix this](https://jsfiddle.net/3ruL67bz/3/) by clearing the canvas between drawing. (I added a random dot function to show this):

```js
var cPushArray = new Array();
var cStep = -1;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// Don't worry about this, I just wrote this for showing random colors
function generateColor() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256).toString(16);
  return '#' + r + g + b;
}

function cPush() {
  cStep++;
  if (cStep < cPushArray.length) {
    cPushArray.length = cStep;
  }
  cPushArray.push(document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL());
}

function cUndo() {
  if (cStep >= 0) {
    cStep--;

    // V Clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // ^ Clear the canvas
    
    var canvasPic = new Image();
    canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
    canvasPic.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}

//This draws the dots on the face.   
function drawCoordinates(x, y) {
  var pointSize = 30; // Change according to the size of the point.
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = generateColor();
  ctx.beginPath(); //Start path
  ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Draw a point using the arc function of the canvas with a point structure.
  ctx.fill(); // Close the path and fill.
  cPush();
}

document.getElementById('buttonUndo').onclick = function() {
  cUndo();
}
document.getElementById('addDot').addEventListener('click', function() {
  drawCoordinates(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #222;
}
canvas {
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
<button id="buttonUndo">Undo</button>
<button id="addDot">Add Dot</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (it basically works like how I want it to in your demo minus the fact that the user doesn't get to draw on the canvas but rather, the circles are added in a random fashion) but unfortunately, when I use the clear and then click undo, my entire canvas image disappears and then when I click  the button. I then tried adding a bunch of random dots inside the blank canvas and then clicking undo but all of them ended up disappearing at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: @somanyerrorswhy Are you only calling `cPush` at the end of `drawCoordinates`? That should be the only time you call it (in this context anyway)

Comment: Yup. Maybe I did something wrong earlier on or something.

Comment: @somanyerrorswhy Did you check your console? (hit F12 on Windows or Opt + Cmd + I on Mac) The canvas is tainted from that. That occurs if you load in data from a different domain than your own. If you need data from a different domain then search Stack Overflow, there's a few questions about that. Otherwise, try running it on your own site. It will work fine.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was a thing! Thank you so much once again!!